# Can't get sub-menu to stay when hovering over it in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, frontend

Trying to get it so when I hover over issues tab, a sub-menu drops, and when you leave the tab it disappears.That part works, however, when user hovers over the sub-menu I want it to remain. That is the part that is not working, it disappears right away even though the set timeout function is set to 3 seconds. I have no idea why it does that.

```js
let timeout;

$('nav > ul li:first-child').on('mouseenter click', function () {
        if ($('.issues').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('.issues').slideDown('slow'); 
        }
        else {
            $('.issues').slideUp();
        } 
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                $('.issues').slideUp();
            }, 3000);
        });

    $('.issues').mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
```

```css
.issues {
    display: none;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
                <li><a>Issues</a></li>
                <ul class="issues">
                    <li><a>X</a></li>
                    <li><a>Y</a></li>
                    <li><a>Z</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
                <li><a>Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The child UL should be IN the LI element and not as a child of the UL

Comment: What difference does that make? I tried it already it makes the CSS more difficult to style after. Regardless, should not affect the slidedown functions of jQuery.

Comment: Run your code through an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) and find out. :) `Error: Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UL should to be in the LI to be valid HTML. With that you have zero need for the sub menu to cancel the timeout since the mouse has not left the LI

```js
let timeout;

$('nav > ul li:has(ul)').on('mouseenter click', function() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeout);
  if ($('.issues').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('.issues').slideDown('slow');
  } else {
    $('.issues').slideUp();
  }
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.issues').slideUp();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.issues {
  display: none;
  position: static;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Issues</a>
      <ul class="issues">
        <li><a>X</a></li>
        <li><a>Y</a></li>
        <li><a>Z</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
    <li><a>Donate</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You were correct thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I'd do something like this:

```js
$('nav > ul > li:first-child').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(ev) {
  const isHidden = $('.issues').css('display') == 'none';

  switch (ev.type) {
    case 'click':
      if (isHidden) {
        $('.issues').slideDown('slow');
      } else {
        $('.issues').slideUp();
      }
      break;

    case 'mouseleave':
      if (!isHidden) {
        $('.issues').slideUp();
      }
      break;

    case 'mouseenter':
      if (isHidden) {
        $('.issues').slideDown();
      }
      break;

    default:
      // Do nothing
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.issues {
  display: none;
  position: static;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Issues</a>
      <ul class="issues">
        <li><a>X</a></li>
        <li><a>Y</a></li>
        <li><a>Z</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
    <li><a>Donate</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```